# two way webservice communication REST

Tags: java, spring, rest, reactive

G'day folks, So I have an application in mind with a client-server architecture where multiple clients are connected to a web service. The webservice needs to be able to call or send messages to all or some of the clients. I have previously done the same using SOAP based services in WCF but now I am working with java and wish to avoid SOAP. I have been experimenting with Server Sent Events in reactive framework in Spring framework but have been mostly unlucky. 
Is there a way to implement two way communication without explicitly exposing a webservice or such on the client? thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try WebSockets for two-way communication and simple Restful for request-response communication.
Here is a simple guide: http://www.baeldung.com/java-websockets

Comment: I'm trying to avoid websockets since a third party library is required to use them on android.

Comment: I've used Atmoshpere framework on Android to consume websockets: https://github.com/Atmosphere/wasync
https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-samples/tree/master/wasync-samples